# Click is not working sometimes when Div is loaded through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending The div in html after i get ajax success response.
E.g :

```
<span class="slick-custom-arrow slick-prev" onclick="slickSlides(this);return false;"><svg width="30" height="37" viewBox="0 0 30 37" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use xlink:href="#pro-arrow-left"></use></svg></span>
```

This is the click function :

```
function slickSlides(el){
    console.log("clicked");
}
```

I add 5-10 div with this span and this function runs randomly, by randomly i mean if click on 4th span the click does not work and some times on 1st it does not work and sometimes it works for all spans.
More confusing thing is **Clicking 1st time does not work and on 2nd click it works**
Does someone has this problem before ?

Comment: We can't help with this unless we see more relevant code. Try creating a [mre].

Comment: since is dynamic added element event should be done like this $(document).on('click', 'element', function(){})

Comment: Use jquery live events as @Ivan said

Comment: @ivan i tried your code as well but the click is still gets missed.

Comment: May be the html structure can be helpful :
    `<span class="slick-custom-arrow slick-prev"><svg width="8" height="13" viewBox="0 0 8 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg></span>
        <a href="https://google.com" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;" tabindex="0">
         <img src="source" class="lozad"  alt="">
        </a>
<span class="slick-custom-arrow slick-next"><svg width="8" height="13" viewBox="0 0 8 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg></span>`    

These span shows On the image itself for sliding to next image

Answer (score 1):

**Event to a parent which already exists.**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".slick-custom-arrow", function() {
   alert('clicked ',$(this).html())
 });
$.ajax({
  url: "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    html.data.forEach(function(el,idx){
       if(idx<=10){
          let data='<br><span class="slick-custom-arrow" > '+(idx+1)+' Span </span>';
          $("#container").append(data);
       }
    })
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="slick-custom-arrow">0 Span</span>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on("click", ".slick-custom-arrow", function() {
   // Your code here
 });
```

Comment: the `live` event is deprecated. Use `on` instead of this.

Comment: this wont work .live event is Deprecated , after jquery 1.9 use .on

Comment: still same issue.

Comment: @aneeb see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i found the issue which is the click of parent div gets triggered rather than triggering the click of the element on which i click.

Comment: click on parrent div would not work as `event` is `bind` with `.slick-custom-arrow` class so make sure parrent div doesn't have same class.